# Regular expression to remove HTML tags without <br/> tab from a string

Tags: java, html, regex

I am currently stuck at generating a regex for the following requirement of the strings `<b>abc<br/></b>` or `xy<i>abcd<br/></i>` or `<th>ab<br/></th>wvx` or etc.

My requirement is to remove `<` and `>` characters of `<b>` or `</b>` or `<i>` or `</i>` or `<th>` or `</th>` etc using java `replaceAll(<regex>,"");` method without replacing the `<` and `>` characters of `<br/>` tag.

Examples:

Input: `<b>abc<br/></b>`
Output should be: `babc<br/>/b`

Input: `xy<i>abcd<br/></i>`
Output should be: `xyiabcd<br/>/i`

Input: `<th>ab<br/></th>wvx`
Output should be: `thab<br/>/thwvx`

....... etc.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: You are expecting the replacements on the strings _with_ `<br/>` tags.  Did you phrase your question wrongly?

Comment: No, actually I want to keep `<br/>`. Please check the examples

Comment: Any time you use regex to parse html, you lose a little bit of your soul. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`</?([a-z]+)>` should do. If slash is after letters it will not match.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I only need to get the match for `<` or  `>` of `<b>` or `</b>` tags. Like `<b>abc<br/></b>` Output should be: `babc<br/>/b`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sure. Full command is `input.replaceAll("</?([a-z]+)>", "$1")`. $1 is changed to whatever is found in round braces.

Comment: Requirements do not mention `<br>` without slash. :) And it looks like some homework. But if `<br>` should be filtered too then my regexp is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It's working perfectly and according to requirement. You saved my day. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `String#replaceAll`:

```
String input = "<b>abc<br/></b>";
input = input.replaceAll("</?(?!br)([^>]+)>", "$1");
System.out.println(input);

babc<br/>b
```

The pattern `</?(?!br)[^>]+)>` will match any opening or closing HTML tag other than `br`.  It will replace that tag with just the text name of the tag.

Note that parsing HTML with regex generally is not a good idea.  This may work in your case if you only have single level HTML as in your example strings.

### Demo

Comment: Tim, Thank you soo much for the answer. It's working perfectly and according to requirement. You saved my day. Thanks!!!